# Proof that $f(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $I= (0,1]$

Tags: analysis, functions, continuity, proof-writing

Let $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ an interval.

How can one prove that $f_1(x)= \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $I= (0,1]$?

I know that$\frac{1}{x}$ isn't continuous nor is it discontinuous at $x_0 = 0$ because it's not defined  and taking $\lim x \to \infty$ would just give $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $f_1(\frac{1}{n})-f_1(\frac{1}{n-1}) = 1$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$.

Hence you have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that the distance between two consecutive points goes towards zero while $f_1(x_{n})-f_1(x_{n-1}) =1$. In contradiction with the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of [uniform continyuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity).

Answer (score 0):

First prove that it is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ because limit at $0$ does not exist finitely.So$f$ fails to be uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$,I am using the theorem that a continuous function on an open interval is uniformly continuous iff the end point limits exist finitely.So the function is not uniformly continuous on the superset $(0,1]$.The actual reason in summary is the funtion does not have a continuous extension to a compact interval.